# CMake - Check if a higher level directory exists

Tags: cmake

I'm new to CMake and I tried to do this in my root CMakeLists.txt :

```
set(HAVE_MY_SDK   OFF)

if(IS_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}../Libs/A")
    if(EXISTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}../Libs/A/CMakeLists.txt")
        set (HAVE_MY_SDK   ON)
    endif()
endif()
```

Currently, CMake is just avoiding the instruction, leaving `HAVE_MY_SDK` in a `OFF` status. Is it possible to check an higher level directory with CMake ? Or maybe doing it with an indirect method

Comment: Do you need this to check if you can use an `add_subdirectory()` on it?

Comment: Yes, I do it later but that's the purpose

Comment: Ok, I thought that being the case. Have added my version of it to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're just missing a `/` after `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Out of completeness here is the code I use for this (note that `if (EXISTS ...)` needs full paths):

```
get_filename_component(_fullpath "${_dir}" REALPATH)
if (EXISTS "${_fullpath}" AND EXISTS "${_fullpath}/CMakeLists.txt")
    ...
```

And here inside my extended `add_subdirectory()` version (including a "add once guard"):

```
function(my_add_subdirectory _dir)
    get_filename_component(_fullpath "${_dir}" REALPATH)
    if (EXISTS "${_fullpath}" AND EXISTS "${_fullpath}/CMakeLists.txt")
        get_property(_included_dirs GLOBAL PROPERTY GlobalAddSubdirectoryOnceIncluded)
        list(FIND _included_dirs "${_fullpath}" _used_index)
        if (${_used_index} EQUAL -1)
            set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY GlobalAddSubdirectoryOnceIncluded "${_fullpath}")
            add_subdirectory(${_dir} ${ARGN})
        endif()
    else()
        message(WARNING "my_add_subdirectory: Can't find ${_fullpath}/CMakeLists.txt")
    endif()
endfunction(my_add_subdirectory)
```

Comment: By full paths I assume you mean something like /Users/Me/My_Project, so it tear down the portability ?

Comment: @JonOsterman No, I just mean you have to prefix something like `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` (that's still portable). Only giving a relative path in `if (EXISTS ...` has undefined behavior.